# Blazor: What does the first character ☱ ☲ ☴ mean in the title?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Normally, the title of an index page should be like:

[image]

But sometimes I will see an additional changing character (when debugging), which seems to mean that there are something being loading:

[image]

This must be a feature rather than a bug, which has no bad influence.

I'm just curious about it.

So what does this character mean here, and when will it appear? Or maybe it isn't a feature of blazor, but of my own browser?

(The character seems to be here when the web browser is still running but the project has been stopped. But when I really want to reproduce this, it seems to be playing hide-and-seek with me...)

Comment: what ide? could it be saying its compiling?

Comment: @DanielA.White Visual Studio. This is the title of the page in the web browser but not in the ide, so... I'm going to have a test.

Comment: @DanielA.White Wow, supposedly you're right! But it will still be like that after compiling. Maybe it means that the page is outdated and a refresh is required. Maybe you shall answer the question so I can accept it?

Comment: It is a Hot Reload Syncing icon...

Comment: @BrianParker But I won't see it when pressing hot reload... Maybe my modification is too slight and it can be reloaded in a very short time..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is part of the Browser Refresh feature - when you see that it is waiting/trying to reconnect to the server - if it stays like that it has lost the connection and you should reload manually

https://cs.github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/e77d401936a2cb7b13c6fc3ba7d793258bb63897/src/BuiltInTools/BrowserRefresh/WebSocketScriptInjection.js#L28

Comment: But the character won't appear when stopping the project, but when compiling it again. (And it's a wasm project)

Comment: You would have to look a the source code to get a full idea of when it happens - I have added a link